# Trying to return 'datetime.date' instead using yield

Tags: python, date, generator, python-datetime

I have this function. It return range dates from today, but I need to use this result twice. If I replace 'yield' with 'return' I got `TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable`

```
def date_range():
    start_date = datetime.date.today()
    end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=11)
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
```

Comment: @mu無: they are locals in the function, the only globals used in the function are `datetime` and `timedelta`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than 'fix' the function, convert the result of the function to a list:

```
dates = list(date_range())
```

The `list()` function then iterates over all the results produced by the generator function and builds a list object from them. You can then iterate over that list object as many times as you like.

The alternative would be to convert the function to return a list rather than generate the date objects one by one:

```
def date_range():
    start_date = datetime.date.today()
    return [start_date + timedelta(n) for n in range(11)]
```

This uses a list comprehension to produce the whole list from the same loop. Note that the `end_date` calculation was entirely redundant since you then go back to a timedelta and even to an integer number of days!

Similarly, your generator function version can be simplified to:

```
def date_range():
    start_date = datetime.date.today()
    for n in range(11):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I was trying to return the result to a list before, but without success.
I'll accept your answer later, because of limit.

Comment: To add to this: Taking Martijn's code and replacing the `[ ]` with `( )` will result in a generator expression which is (semi?) equivalent to the original code and much nicer to read.

Comment: @Voo: not sure I entirely agree about that; I'd say the two versions are equivalent in readability.

Comment: @Martijn Then why not use the explicit version for the list too and push results onto it? I find the list comprehension and generator version nicer to read than the explicit ones, but I guess it's subjective.

Comment: @Voo: yeah, it is a little subjective. I find the `yield` keyword signals better to the reader that a generator is being returned. On the other hand, a list comprehension doesn't materially alter the behaviour of the function.